# Is there a Box with Tabs in shinydashboardPlus?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

im using shinydashboardPlus for my app. In shinydashboard there is a tabBox where I can create tabs. Now im using boxPlus. Is there a possibility to create tabs as well? I could not find it on the internet.

Comment: What do you mean by creating tabs? Can you be more specific?

Comment: No there is no 'tabBoxPlus' but you can still use tabBox from shindashboard